# Select rows with same id and set same value in a row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried for hours and read many posts but I still can't figure out how to handle this request:

I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+------+
|ID    |NAME  |REKEY |
+------+------+------+
|1     |NULL  |AB1C  |
+------+------+------+
|2     |POP   |AB1C  |
+------+------+------+
|3     |NULL  |DE97  |
+------+------+------+
|4     |ANNA  |DE97  |
+------+------+------+
```

When I select, the result is like the table above.

I want to get the value 'POP' from the bottom row and replace it on the top row. Only use select because I am not allowed to update the record.

The result is like below:

```
+------+------+------+
|ID    |NAME  |REKEY |
+------+------+------+
|1     |POP   |AB1C  |
+------+------+------+
|2     |POP   |AB1C  |
+------+------+------+
|3     |ANNA  |DE97  |
+------+------+------+
|4     |ANNA  |DE97  |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: `SELECT coalesce(NAME, 'POP'), REKEY  FROM some_table`? If not you will need to provide more information.

Comment: I want to get the value 'POP' from the bottom row and replace it with the top row

Comment: @DũngNguyễnAnh can you explain your desired output? Maybe add more rows too?

Comment: @Zakaria Sorry, I just updated my question

Comment: In your first table example is the `REKEY` for row 4 supposed to be AB1C or DE97? It changes in the second table and makes it hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try using `max()` :

```
select ID,
max(NAME) over(partition by REKEY) as LIEFNR,
REKEY
from table_name;
```

Comment: It's work, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Table1 is the table with missing values, Also I assumed your REKEY values are same in rows with id 3 & 4 (Let me know if thats not the case). Below will produce the result what you are looking for.

```
select *
from
(
select A.ID, B.LIEFNR, A.REKEY
from
(
select *
from Table1 A
where LIEFNR is null
)A
left join
(
select *
from Table1 B
where LIEFNR is not null
)B
on A.REKEY=B.REKEY 
)K
union 

select *
from Table1 B
where LIEFNR is not null
```